# Missing file after Mobilefirst 7.1 migration of Windows8 app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

After I've migrated my MobileFirst 6.3 apps to MobileFirst 7.1 using MobileFirst Studio, I get an error at build time on my Windows8 environments.  The error points to a file that has been added as a reference in my jsproj file but is missing entirely from my local filesystem.  The missing file is the AuthWinRT.targets file.

```
 [exec] 
 [exec] Build started 2/11/2016 1:27:41 PM.
 [exec] Project "C:\HOME\3Q2016-Blue-app-builddeploy-appx\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AssetAudit.jsproj" on node 1 (Clean;Rebuild;Publish target(s)).
 [exec] C:\HOME\3Q2016-Blue-app-builddeploy-appx\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AssetAudit.jsproj(1471,1): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\HOME\3Q2016-Blue-app-builddeploy-appx\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AuthWinRT.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
 [exec] Done Building Project "C:\HOME\3Q2016-Blue-app-builddeploy-appx\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AssetAudit.jsproj" (Clean;Rebuild;Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
 [exec] 
 [exec] Build FAILED.
 [exec] 
 [exec] "C:\HOME\3Q2016-Blue-app-builddeploy-appx\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AssetAudit.jsproj" (Clean;Rebuild;Publish target) (1) ->
 [exec]   C:\HOME\3Q2016-Blue-app-builddeploy-appx\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AssetAudit.jsproj(1471,1): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\HOME\3Q2016-Blue-app-builddeploy-appx\MaximoAnywhere\apps\AssetAudit\windows8\native\AuthWinRT.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
 [exec] 
 [exec]     0 Warning(s)
```

Comment: Close visual studio,reopen ,clean,rebuild your project

Comment: What is the exact build version of your MFP 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now you could copy AuthWinRT.targets file (you could get it when you create a new project) to the native folder and rebuild the same. Meanwhile we will investigate on the migration issue.

Also, when once you have this file in place you will have to select either 'x86' or 'ARM' or 'X64' platform and rebuild the project. Project will not work with 'AnyCPU'.